# Maven versioning of internal dependencies

Tags: java, maven, version, versioning

Let's assume that we have a project which uses `Maven` and has some `dependencies` which are developed in the same company/team or even by the same person. It is clear that when some developer wants to `compile` the project, the `specified dependencies` will be fetched from the repo and downloaded locally if they are not there yet.

Now let's assume the following scenario:

The developer does **not care** about the dependencies and

1. the version of the dependency is `x.x.x.SNAPSHOT` => `maven` will be fetching the *latest version* from the repo every 24 hours (by default). **Problem**: if this version is not compatible with your project, basically, you don't even know what happened because you did not change anything in your project. The only possible *solution* here is to compile and manage the dependency locally.
2. the version of the dependency is "x.x.x.y" => maven will fetch exactly this version and nothing else. So, to update this dependency I need to change the version. **Problem**: it seems that it means that every time when this dependency gets some changes and code is pushed to the server *the version must be changed*. But this sounds just ridiculous.

*Possible solution:*

It seems that the only possible solution in this case is to handle the `internal dependencies` manually (get the source from repo and compile locally). However, these two issues are bothering me:

1. This solution breaks the whole idea of `maven` which should fetch all the dependencies.
2. This solution will bring difficulties for the developers who just want to start development on the project, but do not care about those dependencies (because those dependencies are not used in the project part that they are working on).

***Is there better solution?***

Comment: If a developer does not care about dependencies than he has simply not taken his job seriously..Furthermore SNAPSHOT means you are under developer which means it will change...Incompatibilities are expressed by the major.minor.patch verison...(if you follow semver)...If you use releases which are immutiable than exactly this will happen that you need to update your dependencies if they have new releases which is than documented in your version control.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that there is no point of using maven if we are all the time compiling manually and locally?

Comment: Maybe that is too much that I said not care, but what I meant is that the developer is not interested in the dependencies, but want's the latest working version, however, this dependency is in development process.

Comment: If a developer likes to have the latest version which is in development the usage of major.minor.patch-SNAPSHOT is the way to go...Apart from that a developer must be aware of dependencies and needs a knowledge about what he is using...there is interest needed...If there are many modules which you need to compile separately you might need to consider to create a multi module build from it...

Answer (score 0):

You can also take care about latest stable dependencies by making your maven to work with your own administrated web repo. So you will be sure that all crew has a plugins,frameworks etc. of version needed. Our team uses TeamCity server for building workbanches, .m2/settings.xml is configured to work with our TC server repo as well. And team-lead is controling all versions.